# State change instead of real delete

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-3

Is it possible to overload `Session.Delete()` behavior to not to perform real deleting from DB but update value of `int State` column to special *deleted* value? And would be great to restrict then loading of deleted entities by `GetAll()` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of a Delete is called Soft Delete. You can use interceptor to override `Session.Delete()` and use `where` on class mapping to define a formula, like:

```
<class where="State=0" ...>
```

Gabriel Schenker has an example on nhforge.org: http://nhibernate.info/blog/2008/09/06/soft-deletes.html

Comment: Hi Miroslav, I have registred Listener and it fires (as post on Gabriel Schenker blog)...but record it's not updated...can you help me?

Comment: @Luigi You should ask this in a new question with a sample of your code. It could be hard to determine what could go wrong without the actual code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296076/soft-delete-nhibernate#comment16495884_12296076