# Soft Delete Nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-3, soft-delete

I want to make a soft delete on my db table...i have apply following statement (as described here http://nhibernate.info/blog/2008/09/06/soft-deletes.html and in a lot of question on SO).
Fattura is my table where i want apply logical delete (there is no trigger on it)

**Fattura.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="Paggentola.Gestionale.DL.Model"   namespace="Paggentola.Gestionale.DL.Model">
  <class name="Fattura" table="Fattura"  where="Cancellato=0">
    <id name="Id_Fattura" column="Id_Fattura">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="Tipo_Fattura" column="Tipo_Fattura" />
    <property name="Cancellato" column="Cancellato" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Fattura.cs** - Model Object

```
using System;

namespace ModelObject
{
    public class Fattura : ISoftDeletable
    {
        public virtual int Id_Fattura { get; set; }     
        public virtual Int16 Id_Tipo_Fattura { get; set; }          
        public virtual Int16 Cancellato { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Delete event Listener**

```
    public class MyDeleteEventListener : DefaultDeleteEventListener
    {
        protected override void DeleteEntity(IEventSource session, object entity,
            EntityEntry entityEntry, bool isCascadeDeleteEnabled,
            IEntityPersister persister, ISet transientEntities)
        {
            if (entity is ISoftDeletable)
            {
                var e = (ISoftDeletable)entity;
                e.Cancellato = 1;

                CascadeBeforeDelete(session, persister, entity, entityEntry, transientEntities);
                CascadeAfterDelete(session, persister, entity, transientEntities);

            }
            else
            {
                base.DeleteEntity(session, entity, entityEntry, isCascadeDeleteEnabled,
                                  persister, transientEntities);
            }
        }
    }
```

Configured in that way

```
configuration.SetListener(ListenerType.Delete, new MyDeleteEventListener());
```

The event fire but it doesn't set Cancellato =1.
This is my DeleteCommand

```
   public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        NHibernateSession.Delete(entity);

        NHibernateSession.Flush();
    }
```

Comment: you need to make `transaction.Open` and `commit` without `commit` it's won't save anything to your db

Comment: wrong because hard delete works fine...

Comment: hard delete in nhibernate got build in transaction or as we speak out of the box

Comment: Agreed. Have you tried with the transaction in your Delete method?

Comment: Sure! Don't work...(p.s. Flush must be same effect..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error on my mapping file. Property

```
 <property name="Cancellato" column="Cancellato" />
```

haven't same name in my database column. In that way it's not updated. I just don't understand why at runtime there is no error...

I have set same name and work fine.